# How to override overloaded functions in python

Tags: python, qt, overloading, overriding, squish

(Python squish)
I am overriding the following methods-

```
installEventHandler(eventName, handlerFunctionName);

installEventHandler(className, eventName, handlerFunctionName);

installEventHandler(object, eventName, handlerFunctionName);
```

In my method,

```
def MyinstallEventHandler(???)
```

I am not sure what should I  define in my function, so that I can override all the methods.

When I try to pass *args, its considered as tuple and does not match any of the above methods.

The overloaded methods are that of squish. I want to override the above three methods and I am unable to find any solution to this.

Comment: Python doesn't have overloaded functions.

Comment: Also, if you pass `*args`, it's not considered as a tuple; it's expanded into separate arguments. For example, `args = [1,2,3]; f(*args)` calls `f(1, 2, 3)`. You may be mixing up what happens when you _accept_ `*args` in your `def`. In that case, you _do_ get all the arguments as a tuple—but to then pass them on as separate arguments, you just use `*args` again in the call. Which may be exactly what you're looking for here.

Comment: Seems like `eventName` and `handlerFunctionName` are both mandatory; perhaps a single function that accepts `className` or `object` as optional argument (defaulting to `None`)?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at these [examples](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/6.3/ugs-eventhandlers.html), it appears that calling `installEventHandler(*args)`, where `args` is a tuple of suitable arguments (2 or 3), is sufficient. If you want to create your own `installEventHandler` which uses other parameters, just create what you want to create and do it so that you may call the original `installEventHandler`.

## A note about overloading:

Built-in Python does not allow to handle overloading. However, you may want to use a single dispatch, which allows you to handle simple cases depending on the type of the **first** argument. The `singledispatch` decorator is implemented in [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html).

The package [overloading](https://pypi.org/project/overloading/) provides you a more complex support for overloading functions by looking at the types of your arguments. Depending on your Python version, you might need to change some lines in order to preserve `typing` compatibility.

In your case, it would be impossible to apply these solutions, for your original methods are not decorated with the suitable decorators.